# Python Multiple .PNG Files per PDF Page

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I am relatively new to the Python-PDF relationship.  If I had a list of .PNG files/pictures, how would I go about creating a PDF document with these files/pictures?  And is it possible to have, for example, 4 per page?  I would not need any other formatting... the requirement is very basic.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a python-reportlab solution, but based on your requirement, you probably don't need it. You can simply use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) to accomplish the same.

First merge multiple PNGs into one PNG destined to be one page

```
montage -mode concatenate a*.png group_a.png
montage -mode concatenate b1.png b2.png b3.png b4.png group_b.png
...
```

Then simply

```
convert group_*.png one.pdf
```

The resulting PDF would have 2 pages, each of which contains multiple PNGs.

Answer (score 0):

The python program img2pdf will store images into PDFs (it might not work on some PNGs, though), and there are several n-up examples in Python for putting multiple images on a page.  My own library pdfrw has a 4-up example script with it.  (The generic term for n-up for printing purposes is "page imposition", so that is sometimes a good search term.)